# hexapdf page orientation and content sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using `hexapdf` for pdf creation and newbie in this gem so I want some solutions about the following issues.

1) How to set page content from top instead of bottom in `hexapdf` gem's page and how can we give height, width and at parameters in percentage."

2) how can import new font in this.

please give me some solution for these problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answers are below.

1) `composer` will help to create a doc from top to bottom.

2) import font like this.

example:

```
HexaPDF::Composer.create('composer.pdf') do |pdf|
  font_name = "path_of_file.ttf"
  text_style = pdf.base_style.dup.update(font: font_name)
  pdf.text("this is some text", style: text_style)
end
```